# Multiple Game Instances

Tags: lance

Im playing around with Lance, and i was wondering how you would manage multiple games on a single server. Let's say a game can have a Max of 5 users, how would this setup look? Thanks in advance.

Erik

Comment: This is probably where rooms comes in unless you really specifically want more server instances.